# How to change the font color of the edittext magnifying glass

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

In Android, How to change the font color of the edittext magnifying glass ?

[image]

Comment: Magnifing glass just shows what is drawn on the screen (if EditText is overlapped by some other View, it will show that View)

Comment: @LeoLeontev but i need to be change the background color (or the font color) of the magnifing glass is it possible ?